# Increase/Expand height of the electron window on button click

Tags: javascript, react-native, electron

The first image which is having fixed height and width
[image: First image which is having fixed height and width]

The second image I want to set the height of the electron window on click of Details button only if the message is too big. How can I do this?

[image: Second image I want to set the height of the electron window on click of Details button only if the message is too big. How can I do this ?]

Answer (score 0):

You can access BrowserWindow from you **renderer** process:

```
var currentWindow = require("electron").remote.getCurrentWindow();
var currentSize = currentWindow.getSize();
var animate = true;
currentWindow.setSize(currentSize[0], currentSize[1] + 100, animate);
```

Not forget to set **nodeIntegration** to *true* in BrowserWindow constructor in **main** process:

```
var messageWindow = new BrowserWindow({ webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true } })
```